# How user aws EventBridge to reboot instance when env degraded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to use the event bridge to reboot my degraded ec2 instance whenever the beanstalk changes to warn status, at the destination there is the option to call a lambda function or use the api reboot instance, my doubt is how to get the id of the instance only degraded (Taking into account that my environment has 2 instances).

Answer (score 1):

when Elastic Beanstalk dispatches an event for a [health status change](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.eventbridge.html#eb-eventbridge-examples), it looks like:

```
{ 
   "version":"0",
   "id":"1234a678-1b23-c123-12fd3f456e78",
   "detail-type":"Health status change",
   "source":"aws.elasticbeanstalk",
   "account":"111122223333",
   "time":"2020-11-03T00:34:48Z",
   "region":"us-east-1",
   "resources":[
      "arn:was:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:111122223333:environment/myApplication/myEnvironment"
   ],
   "detail":{
      "Status":"Environment health changed",
      "EventDate":1604363687870,
      "ApplicationName":"myApplication",
      "Message":"Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Ok. Initialization completed 1 second ago and took 2 minutes.",
      "EnvironmentName":"myEnvironment",
      "Severity":"INFO"
   }
}
```

in your AWS Lambda, you can use any [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html#cli-aws-elasticbeanstalk) command, using the AWS SDK for your language of choice,

using the [AWS JavaScript SDK for Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticBeanstalk.html), you can restart your environment with `restartAppServer`:

```js
 var params = {
  EnvironmentName: event.detail.EnvironmentName // based on the sample above
 };
 elasticbeanstalk.restartAppServer(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

in the example above we would trigger a restart for all instances in the environment.

to target a specific instance, you can use [describe-instances-health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-instances-health.html), renamed to [`describeInstancesHealth`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticBeanstalk.html#describeInstancesHealth-property) in the AWS JavaScript SDK:

```js
var params = {
  AttributeNames: ["HealthStatus"],
  EnvironmentName: event.detail.EnvironmentName,
};
elasticbeanstalk.describeInstancesHealth(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

based on its response, you can filter the instance that isn't OK and trigger a restart using the instance id by calling the [EC2 API `rebootInstances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#rebootInstances-property):

```js
 var params = {
  InstanceIds: [
     "i-1234567890abcdef5"
  ]
 };
 ec2.rebootInstances(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, you gave me several points in the documentation that I had not yet found, I will try to implement and give feedback